Unable to Capture Memory dotnet-gcdumps from Android Emulator for .NET MAUI Application
I am following the documentation below for checking memory in a .NET MAUI application on the Android platform: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/tracing.md#how-to-get-gc-memory-dumps
However, when I run the command "dotnet-gcdump ps" to find the process id of the Android emulator, the emulator process id is not shown in the list. I found the process id of the emulator manually and tried to collect the gcdump "dotnet-gcdump collect -p 33972", but it failed to write. I have attached a screenshot of the issue.


The emulator is not a .NET application, only the app that is running inside it's virtual Android OS uses Mono/.NET. I am not sure if it is possible to run dotnet-gcduml inside the virtual Android system.

The memory leak documentation below states that the gcdump is available for the Android platform in the .NET 8 version. I am using the same version but I couldn't find the process ID of the emulator, causing it to fail to write the gcdump. Can you please provide suggestions on how to check for memory leaks on the Android platform?
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Memory-Leaks

I don't think gcdump would work even if you would have the emulator process ID: An emulator is a black box. gcdump can not know or access the app memory that is running inside. If you have gcdump for Android push it into the Android emulator and execute it from within he emulator. Note that you ca not execute something from the /sdcard or /storage/emulated/0 path. So push gcdump to /sdcard and then copy it to a place where you can execute it e.g. /data/local/ set the executable bit via chmod and execute it on the MAUI app's process id.
